# How can share bean from external library to GWT client?

Tags: java, gwt, javabeans

I have a question about share the java bean in library to gwt client
I know bean share between GWT client and server usually put into package domain.shared.

However, how can I make use of existing bean from external jar library on GWT client?

Because I always got this message.
No source code is available for type xxxx.xxxx.bean did you forget to inherit a required module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your beans are in the package `xxx.xxx.bean`, and they are in an imported `my_beans.jar` library.

Create a folder in your Application `src` tree (or `src/main/java` if you are using maven) with the name `xxx/xxx`

Create a new Module file in this folder called `MyBeans.gwt.xml` with this content:

```
<module>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <source path="bean"/>
</module>
```

Edit your `Application.gwt.xml` and add this line

```
<inherits name="xxx.xxx.MyBeans"/>
```

Be aware that all Classes in the `xxx.xxx.bean` package must use classes supported by GWT.

You should check as well that the `my_beans.jar` library includes the java source files of the beans you are going to use.

Answer (score 3):

1) You can only include beans from the external jar library provided it is GWT compatible and declares a `<ThirdPartyModuleName>.gwt.xml` file which includes the package for the beans you need to use.

2) You should have the `<ThirdPartyModuleName>` included in your own `<Module>.gwt.xml` using `<inherits>` tag.