# GWT : How to use beans from separate module?

Tags: java, gwt, javabeans, gwt-rpc

I am working on a project with seperated modules . **backend** for *admins* , **client** for *users* and **core** for share DAO layer amongs **backend** and **client**. 
**backend** module uses GWT and **client** uses Spring MVC. At **backend** module , **core** module was included by [deployment assembly](http://eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.2.0/NewAndNoteworthy/javaee.php). My server side , DAOs are injected by Spring. 
All beans(POJOs) created in **core** module. My problem is I would like to use these beans from **core** module in my gwt project (**backend** module) or when using RPC calls. 
 I tried as answers of [How can share bean from external library to GWT client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647270/how-can-share-bean-from-external-library-to-gwt-client) question but didn't satisfy yet. I got below error

> No source code is available for type
>   com.mycom.core.business.bean.TestBean; [ERROR] Hint: Check the
>   inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a
>   required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries
>   properly

Here is my efforted codes ...

**TestBean.java**

```
public class TestBean {
private int id;

public final int getId() {
    return id;
}

public final void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

**beans.gwt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>
   <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
   <source path="com.mycom.core.business.bean.TestBean"/>
</module>
```

Inherit beans.gwt.xml in my App.gwt.xml as `<inherits name='com.mycom.backend.beans'/>` . What am I missing ?

> Edit: Add sample project file

Now I created and uploaded sample modules. You can download it from [google-drive URL](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5jEahfsRItKci11cW54enFrVXc/view?usp=sharing).This archive file contains both **backend** and **core** modules.

- **core** module was created as simple java project from Eclipse IDE.
- **backend** module was created by gwt-ecliplse plugin *(2.7 gwt version and include generated codes)* and add Dynamic Web Module 2.5 project faces.

Finally , I build and run with *GWT-Eclipse plugin* and you can check screen-shoot for

*ClassPath*

[image]
*Source LookUp Path*

[image]
*Modules*

[image]
Below is error log in my console

```
Super Dev Mode starting up
workDir: /var/folders/mt/5287l4j94jd9rfqwqdqxr9zw0000gq/T/gwt-codeserver-7296341534601698800.tmp
Loading Java files in com.mycom.backend.App.
Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
Finding entry point classes
  Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.mycom.backend.client.Backend'
     [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Applications/springsource/workspace/backend/src/com/mycom/backend/client/Backend.java'
        [ERROR] Line 41: No source code is available for type com.mycom.core.business.bean.TestBean; did you forget to inherit a required module?
  [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
[WARN] Server class 'com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JDBCUnloader' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
[WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/Users/cataclysm/Desktop/eclipse%20(Luna)/Datas/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-dev.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
For additional info see: file:/Users/cataclysm/Desktop/eclipse%20(Luna)/Datas/gwt-2.7.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module file for `beans` should be in the `core` folder/library.
Try moving it to `core/src/com/mycom/` and modify the source path accordingly in `beans.gwt.xml`:

```
<source path="core"/>
```

Remember, it is relative to the module file.

Then modify the entry in `App.gwt.xml`:

```
<inherits name='com.mycom.beans'/>
```

I'm not familiar with deployment assembly, but make sure that the `beans.gwt.xml` is present in the resulting library jar (or is copied along with the sources).

Comment: you don't know how many I thank to you . Thanks a lot indeed for your help.

Comment: Glad I was able to help - had to go through the same ordeal when I was setting up my own project, so I know how troublesome it can be :)

Answer (score 2):

The source path of your core module should be accessible to the GWT compile process. Make sure that it is added to either the classpath or the source lookup path.

Comment: As I described , I add my ***core*** module via *deployment assembly*.  So this can see on Right click on ***backend*** module > Java Build Path > Projects , Order and Export tabs. I also added Class Folder from Libraries tab to my ***bean*** folder , but the error was still has.

Comment: And how exactly do you build your app module?

Comment: I build and run with GWT Eclipse plugin , not with maven.

Comment: Ok, so you get a run configuration. Can you check the classpath of that run configuration? In my case I needed to add the folders there explicitly for the compiler to pick up the sources.

Comment: Yes yes .. these are also included by deployment assembly  under **User Entries**.